# Update a column table everytime a new row is added

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to insert data into a DB. I have a table called games and it's defined this way :

```
ID  |  Score  |  Rank
```

I want the rank column to be updated everytime a new row is added. Rank column have to sort Games by score.

For example :

```
ID  |  Score  |  Rank
1   |    5    |   2
2   |    9    |   1
```

When I add a new row (ID=3, Score=15) my table will be like this :

```
ID  |  Score  |  Rank
1   |    5    |   3
2   |    9    |   2
3   |   15    |   1
```

I have tried this in PHP but it dosen't seem to work :

```
try {
   $bdd->exec("INSERT INTO games(score) VALUES('$score')");
} catch (Exception $e) {
   die ($e->getMessage());
}

try {
       $bdd->exec("UPDATE games set rank=(SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 
       AS rank FROM games g, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
       ORDER BY  score;)");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       die ($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Any ideas how can this be done with PHP ? Or is there a way to set the column value by default to be the rank of the scores ?

Comment: Please explain "but it dosen't seem to work" in detail. What _does_ happen? Are you getting errors? If so, what are the exact error messages? If not, in what way does the actual result differ from the desired result?

Comment: No the column rank is set to 0 by default and stays 0 after executing the code.

Comment: how do you want to handle case with matching scores? Ex: If 20 players get score of 25, do you want all 20 to have same rank or should they be ordered by ID?

Comment: They should be ordered by ID.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   $bdd->exec("SET @pos := 0;
   UPDATE games SET rank= ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 ) ORDER BY score DESC;)");
} catch (Exception $e) {
   die ($e->getMessage());
}
```

This worked for me. Thanks anyway.